# WCF REST WebGet for user defined parameters

Tags: wcf

I have below operation contract with WebGet defined as follows.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "UpdateUserDetails/?configdata={_userConfigData}&configresult={_configResult}&clientip={_clientIP}&adminname={AdminName}")]
public void UpdateUserDetails(UserConfigData _userConfigData, ConfigResult _configResult, string _clientIP, string AdminName)
```

When I run the service, I am getting below error. Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Operation 'UpdateUserDetails' in contract 'UserConfigService' has a query variable named '_userConfigData' of type Service1.WCF.UserConfig.UserConfigData', but type 'Service1.WCF.UserConfig.UserConfigData' is not convertible by 'QueryStringConverter'.  Variables for UriTemplate query values must have types that can be converted by 'QueryStringConverter'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that you use Json object to request data.
it should be like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "UpdateUserDetails?_clientIP={_clientIP}&AdminName={AdminName}", Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
public void UpdateUserDetails(UserConfigData _userConfigData, ConfigResult _configResult, string _clientIP, string AdminName)
```

And JSON data seems to be like this:

```
{
    "_userConfigData":{
        "Property1":"value",
        "Property2":"value",
        "Property3":"value"
        ..and so on...
    },
    "_configResult":{
        "Property1":"value",
        "Property2":"value",
        "Property3":"value"
        ..and so on...
    }
}
```

There is a good application for testing Rest services, you can try to use:

[Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

**Additional Info**

In response to the result "**getting Method not found**"
You may not have defined the endpoint or the service address properly. Your webconfig file should have this kind of config.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="soapBinding">
      <security mode="None"></security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webBinding"></binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
      <enableWebScript/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="defaultServiceBehavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <!-- USING SOAP-->
  <service behaviorConfiguration="defaultServiceBehavior" name="MyProject.WCF.UserConfig.UserConfigService">
    <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="soapBinding" contract="MyProject.WCF.UserConfig.IUserConfigService"></endpoint>
  </service>
  <!-- USING JSON-->
  <service behaviorConfiguration="defaultServiceBehavior" name="MyProject.WCF.UserConfig.UserConfigService">
    <endpoint address="json" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior" contract="MyProject.WCF.UserConfig.IUserConfigService"></endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The address seems like this:

```
SOAP
localhost:1706/soap/UserConfigService.svc

JSON
localhost:1706/json/UserConfigService.svc
```

For better reference you could try to watch here:

[How to create simple REST Based WCF Service with JSON format](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IT3bNLNwMuE)

Comment: Thanks, I tried this with POST. But when I try to access the method from browser as shown below, I am getting Method not found. Any ideas? http://localhost:1706/WCF/UserConfig/UserConfigService.svc/UpdateUserDetails?configdata=test&configresult=test3@&clientip=localhost

Answer (score 0):

you have to use string, u cant use an object as query string prameters. it wont convert your query string to an object. those variables should be defined as string.

Comment: Thanks, how do I convert from string to user defined object? Can you please provide me a sample?

Comment: i dont have a sample right now. but once u get the parameter in your implementation than u can create whatever object you need right there. it makes sense no? a HTTP URL doesnt know what your object is.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a link on implementing a custom `QueryStringConverter`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/08/09/wcf-extensibility-querystringconverter.aspx), which will do what you want it to. **Note also** (mentioned in that post) that it might be better to pass a (possibly) complicated object like `UserConfigData` or `ConfigResult` as POST data, rather than in the URL. Considering your method is called "UpdateUserDetails", it's probably best to use a POST (`WebInvoke`) instead of a GET (`WebGet`) anyway, in the spirit of REST.